# How to use jenkins for CI with perforce

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

Looking for some information on how to setup Perforce and Jenkins for CI. Any kick start information will be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/P4+Plugin
for Perforce Integration.
Also one of the key plugin you would need in future for CI would be https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin

Comment: Thanks OMkar for posting those links. But I am hoping to see a fully developed example, if anyone can share that would be of great help.

Comment: Hi OMkar, do you have any step by step installation guide for MAC?

Comment: Tried all googling, encountered lot of problems.

Comment: Also why is it making a difference when using VPN, While on VPN it uses localhost and while not on VPN I have to use my actual ip address to access from browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Perforce Plugin for jenkins. Check 
     [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Perforce+Plugin)

Comment: Hi no1, I tried using the links but they are all very high level and does not really start from scratch, especially installing on MAC machine. Can you post me something like Step by Step installation guide or something, thanks!!